# how to render cards based on distance array

Tags: javascript, reactjs

```
data={id: 20, name: 'Yoda', height: 0.66, mass: 13, gender: 'male', …}
distance=[[15277.712059994128, 9096.467900013797, 2693.8381772957678,...]
```

Hi, I have data fetched from api and distance array. Distance array is calculated distance between each data object on map and the point where i clicked on map.How can i sort objects and render it on my card depends on the distance closest to farthest?

Here is the card list

```
    const CardList = ({ data, distance }) => {

  return (
    <div className='card-list'>
      <div className='card-list_container'>
        {data.map((hero) => {
          return <Card key={hero.id} id={hero.id} distance={distance} />;
        })}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default CardList;
```

And this is the card

```
const Card = ({ id, distance }) => {
  const data = useHeroData({ id });
 return (
    <div className='card'>
      <div className='card-container'> 
          <p className='hero-stats'>
                <span className='hero-stats_tag'>Mass:</span> {data.mass} kg
              </p>
              <p className='hero-stats'>
                {' '}
                <span className='hero-stats_tag'>Distance:</span>
                {Math.ceil(data.distance)} Km
              </p>
            </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot just concat an array to an object. Convert an array to an object first.

```
 function arrayToObject( distance ){
 return  JSON.parse( JSON.stringify( distance ) );
}
var p = [[15277.712059994128, 9096.467900013797, 2693.8381772957678,..]];
obj = new arrayToObject( p );
```

Than this might work

```
Math.ceil(data.distance)
```

Comment: how can i put distance array in data object like distance:15277.712059994128,

Comment: data.distance=15277.712059994128

Comment: But if you are dealing with large amounts of data you should consider turning all to an object with JSON.parse that way you dont have to do it manually